# angular page not loading after angular resource is called

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am making a Dispatchsystem for the local taxi company using angular. I am not a pro at angular and all it's functionalities so I need some help with the following. I was setting up angular-route so I can inject html pages in to the main html document and after that I set up a factory to request the data from my REST-service I had written in java using springboot. After I had succesfully recieved my data I noticed that my test page did not load anymore without the browser console giving me any errors.

These are my documents:

main index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>dispatch</title>

        <!--bootstrap stylesheet-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>

        <!--custom stylesheet-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css"/>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="DispatchApp">

        <ng-view ng-controller="AppCtrl">

        </ng-view>


        <!--import libraries-->
        <script src="node_modules/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="node_modules/angular-resource/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
        <script src="node_modules/angular-route/angular-route.min.js"></script>
        <script src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

        <!--application imports-->
        <script src="index.js"></script>
        <script src="modules/views/index.js"></script>
        <script src="modules/views/vehicles/index.js"></script>
        <script src="modules/services/index.js"></script>
        <script src="modules/services/api/index.js"></script>
        <script src="modules/services/api/vehicles/index.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I made a test html file to see if it gets loaded in the ng-view tag
it just contains a p tag with some text.

main controller of all the views:

```
angular.module("DispatchApp.views",['ngRoute', 'DispatchApp.views.vehicles'])

    //Default Route
    .config(function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.otherwise("/vehicles");
    })
    .controller('AppCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){

    }]);
```

The contoller of my test view:

```
angular.module('DispatchApp.views.vehicles', ['ngRoute'])

.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/vehicles',
    {
        templateUrl: 'modules/views/vehicles/index.html',
        controller: 'viewsVehiclesController',
        reloadOnSearch: false,
        resolve:
        {
            resolvedVehiclesListing: [ 'VehicleApi', function(VehicleApi)
            {
                return VehicleApi.query().$promise;
            }]
        }
    });

}])


.controller('viewsVehiclesController',['$scope', 'resolvedVehiclesListing', function ($scope, resolvedVehiclesListing)
{
    //console.log(resolvedVehiclesListing.data);
    //$scope.vehicles = resolvedVehiclesListing.data;
}])
```

the api service and the factory i use to fetch the data from the backend:

```
angular.module('DispatchApp.services.api', ['ngResource', 'DispatchApp.services.api.vehicles'])
.service('PrefixService', [function()
{
    var prefix = 'http://localhost:8080/';
    var Prefix = function()
    {
        return prefix;
    };

    return {Prefix : Prefix};
}])
.factory('DispatchApiResource', ['$resource', 'PrefixService', function($resource, PrefixService)
{
    return function(endpoint, a, config)
    {
        return $resource(PrefixService.Prefix() + endpoint, a , config);
    };
}])
.factory('VehicleApi', ['DispatchApiResource', function(DispatchApiResource)
{
    return DispatchApiResource('vehicle/:id', null,
        {
            'query': {method: 'GET', isArray: false},
            'update': {method: 'PUT', params: {id: "@id"}}
        });
}]);
```

I don't know why the test html file is not being injected into the ng-view tag eventhough the data was received from the backend, the html file to be displayed is being loaded in the network tab of my bowser (google chrome) and I have no errors in the console.

here is my complete directory structure:

```
/dispatch-frontend
    index.html
    index.js
    /css
       index.css
    /modules
        /services
            index.js
            /api
                index.js
                /vehicles
                    index.js
        /views
            index.js
            /vehicles
                index.html
                index.js
```

Sorry for the long post but I am desperate here.

Comment: What does your `'modules/views/vehicles/index.html'` template look like? Maybe it just doesn't display anything because its empty?

Comment: Sadly it does contains the following <p>GREAT SUCCES</p>. When I remove the 'resolve' from the 'DispatchApp.views.vehicles' module the page loads just fine.

Comment: A free tip: don't use the minified libraries when you are debugging. Use `angular.js` instead

Comment: thank you for the tip. I guess I haven't had much need to sniff around in the code of the frameworks I use.

Answer (score 0):

You have a `resolve` function, which takes a `VehicleApi` service, but that service is registered in the `DispatchApp.services.api`, which isn't referenced anywhere, so the resolve will hang:

```
angular.module('DispatchApp.services.api', ..)
.factory('VehicleApi', ['DispatchApiResource', function(DispatchApiResource)
{
    ..
}]);
```

I think you forgot to lay a dependency on your api module:

```
angular.module('DispatchApp.views.vehicles', [
    'ngRoute',
    'DispatchApp.services.api'
])
```

Comment: I have registered that service with a module **DispatchApp.services** witch is likewise registered with the main **DispatchApp** module. The problem is that I have not much to go on since I get no error in the console. I have tried your suggestion with the same result...

Comment: Yeah so your Main knows the services, Main knows the views, but the module where you want to use the services doesn't know the services

Comment: I don't think thats true because the sevice is called and the data gets pulled from the server.